# How to load a file variying number of columns in every row to Sybase IQ

Tags: sap-iq

I have a comma delimited file in the below format.

1,sdfdf,fafg
2,adfdf,fgrfg,srfgethth,fhgetht
2,fhhh
2,rfghsh,dfgdfg,dfsghs

My table will have 5 columns. Is it possible to load the file in above format to Sybase IQ database?

Comment: The numbers in the indicates the start of new row.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a load command where the field delimiter is a comma ',' and the row delimiter a space ' '. Have in mind that if there are multiple spaces somewhere the load will fail